# Shading changes between eevee and cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Okay, I'm having some shading issues when I render in cycles which I don't have when I render in Eevee is there a way to fix the issues in cycles, I would prefer to use cycles for my renders, Thanks.
The image with the blue circle is eevee the shading is flat, but in cycles the one with red there are some shading issues.

[image: EEVEE]

[image: Cycles]

Comment: Hello, is it shade flat? Maybe share this part of your object?

Comment: Does this part of the object render this way if rendered in isolation, or if you rotate any HDR lighting? The 'issue' could be the result of genuine indirect lighting, not represented in your EEVEE setup.  Do you have some kind of (possibly unnecessary) AO influencing the cycles render?

Comment: It's a game asset, that part is not flat shaded but It has a normal map.

Comment: I do have an AO map added to the basecolor in cycles, let me check if disabling it changes anything, but I would need the AO map since some detail are not real geometry but normal details and their shadows scan only be represented through the normal map.